# Eclipse (Luna), icon, red dot, SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

What does that little red dot overlaying the folder icon in Eclipse Navigator view with SVN mean?

[image]

Comment: Which plugin for SVN are you using? Subversive, Subclipse, something else? Upload image to any online service (such as http://tinypic.com/) and share a link.

Comment: Subclipse. Here's a link to the image https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byue42tLLhjKcUdRYTdKX1ZiMlk